# Terrible sound listening to Radio 1 on iPlayer specifically

Tags: mac, flash, iplayer

Just recently while listening to radio 1 online, the sound quality has become horrible, sounds all crackly and underwater. I've tried reinstalling Flash, and radios 2/3/4 sound fine.

It almost sounds like there are two playing at once.

When I listen to it through a WMA stream (Flip4Mac), it's fine. Any ideas?

Mac OS 10.6.3
Flash 10.0.45.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems other people are encountering this error - [Radio 1 sound quality](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=40630206)